# Call to a member function format() on a non-object DateTime

Tags: php

This problem might be common but it seems like I can't find out what I did wrong.

I have two variables the date and time from database which I think is in UTC format and I need to convert to AEST;

```
$date = message['date']; //25/09/2014
$time = message['time']; //9:00:00

$combined_time = $date . " " . $time;
$schedule_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$combined_time ,new DateTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));
return $schedule_date->format("jS-A-Y H:i:s T");
```

I got `Call to a member function format() on a non-object`  exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use (`"d/m/Y h:i:s"`):

```
$schedule_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y h:i:s", $combined_time , new DateTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));
```

The given format is wrong because your date-time is as `25/09/2014 9:00:00`. <del>Check [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YiIRo6)</del>.

Comment: Thanks @Star, removed it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating any object of class so giving you error you need to create class object or use directly.

```
$schedule_date = new DateTime($date);
return $schedule_date->format("jS-A-Y H:i:s T");
```

or you need to pass `correct format in Datetime()` see **@The Alpha** answer for this

For more read manual :- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Thanks, I just got it now. I think I just did the wrong format in `DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s")`.

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` works, no need to use `new DateTime`

Comment: [Check this working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YiIRo6). `DateTime::createFromFormat` returns a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Yes your approach is also right but you said `You are not creating any object of class` and it's not because `OP` didn't used `new` but for wrong `format` in his `DateTime::createFromFormat` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // convert string to timestamp
    $timeStamp = strtotime($combined_time);
    // create DateTime object use timestamp
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp($timeStamp);
```

Then you can use $date->format('Y') to get year...